# Integral with a compact supported function $0$ indicates the $L^2$ function $0$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose we have $f\in L^2([0,1])$,and for every $\varphi\in C_{0}^{\infty}((0,1))$, we have
$$\int_0^1 f(x)\varphi(x)dx=0$$

Then how can I show $f=0$ a.e? I know when $f\in C^0([0,1])$ the results holds, and $L^2([0,1])$ is the closure of $C^0([0,1])$ with the $L^2$ norm. What I am trying to do is supposing we have a sequence $\{f_n\}\in C^0([0,1])$ converging to $f$ in the $L^2$ norm, then we have

$$\left(\int_0^1 (f_n-f)\varphi dx\right)^2\leq \int_0^1 |f_n-f|^2 dx \int_0^1 |\varphi|^2dx\rightarrow 0$$

So $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f_n\varphi dx\rightarrow 0$. Then I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that $C_0^\infty((0,1))$ is dense in $L^2([0,1])$, a natural approach is to do what you did: take a sequence $\phi_n$ in $C_0^\infty((0,1))$ converging to $f$ in $L^2$ and obtain, 
$$
\int_0^1 |f|^2 = \int_0^1 (f-\phi_n)\overline{f} \le \|f-\phi_n\|_{L^2}\|f\|_{L^2}\to 0 
$$
hence $\int_0^1 |f|^2=0$.

Without the density result, I would use a different approach, which also works for other $L^p$ spaces. Suppose that the set $\{x:f(x)\ne 0\}$ has positive measure. Then it contains some  Lebesgue point of $f$, say $a$. This implies that the averages 
$$\frac{1}{2h}\int_{a-h}^{a+h} f(x)\,dx$$
approach some nonzero value $y\ne 0$. Take a symmetric [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function#Examples) $\phi$ centered at $0$ and supported on $[ -h, h]$. Integration by parts and symmetry yields
$$ \int_0^1 f(x)\phi(x-a)\,dx
= -\int_0^h \phi'(s)\int_{a-s}^{a+s}f(x)\,dx\,ds
$$
which is nonzero for small $h$, since $\phi'$ is negative and the integrals of $f$ all have the same sign.

Comment: Why it contains some lebesgue point? I think it could be all discrete points but there are more than countable many of them so the non zero set is of positive measure.